# Fullscreen ImageView from fragment in a pager adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-imageview

Okay so I have an Activity which contains a FragmentPagerAdapter. One of the fragments is called ProfileFragment, which gets an image via an AsyncTask and loads the image into an ImageView. How can I get the ImageView to occupy the whole screen, including the PagerTabStrip (but not the action bar)?

EDIT: What I mean is I have an Activity that contains a Fragment that contains an ImageView, and I want this ImageView to occupy the whole screen. How can I do this?

EDIT 2: Here's the code for the xml of the Activity, which contains a PagerTabStrip and ViewPager (of Fragments):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:background="#ff000000">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/contact">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:textColor="#bcff8527"
            android:textAppearance="@style/PagerTabStripText"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Contact!"
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#bcff8527"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

There is a FragmentPagerAdapter attached to the ViewPager. The xml of the fragment which contains the ImageView (profile_image) that I want to occupy the full screen is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:alpha="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=">>"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingRight="18dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/scroll">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/rl">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sex"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_perm_identity_white_18dp"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Location"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_info_white_18dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/sex"
                />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location_on_white_18dp"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/Location"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/name"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:gravity="center" />

            </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your current code.

Comment: @spacitron What code would you like? This is slightly confidential, so can you please tell me what you want me to clarify?

Comment: Can't help you if we don't know what you're doing. If the code is confidential you can post a stripped down version of it, provided that it presents the same problems.

Comment: @Mathguy, your question is not clear plase show the your code or improve your question

Comment: I have clarified, please look into it!

Comment: you need to post your whole code, what is your xml doing, cant you do match_parent for height and width?

Comment: Added code too, please check!